# vertex shader without attributes

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, glsles, opengl-es-3.0

Can we have vert shader without attributes?

```
#version 300 es
out mediump vec4 basecolor;

uniform ivec2 x1;

void main(void)
{
        if(x1 == ivec2(10,20))
                basecolor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        else
              basecolor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);

        gl_PointSize = 64.0;
        gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}



#version 300 es
in mediump vec4 basecolor;

out vec4 FragColor;
void main(void)
{
        FragColor =  basecolor;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what hardware platform are you running that has OpenGL ES 3.0? I'm really interested in giving it a go because it's finally approaching the capability level of desktop OpenGL in certain things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically there is nothing in the specification that actually requires you to have vertex attributes. But by the same token, in OpenGL ES 3.0 you have two intrinsically defined `in` attributes whether you want them or not:

> The built-in vertex shader variables for communicating with fixed functionality are intrinsically declared as follows in the vertex language:

```
in highp int gl_VertexID;
in highp int gl_InstanceID;
```

This is really the only time it actually makes sense not to have any attributes. You can dynamically compute the position based on `gl_VertexID`, `gl_InstanceID` or some combination of both, which is a major change from OpenGL ES 2.0.